# How to Make Breadcrumb Responsive?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I Have Issue with my Breadcrumb responsiveness.
I Need to Change Breadcrumb Size, my breadcrumbs size is the same in both devices desktop and mobile, how I can small my breadcrumb size in mobile devices only...

I Tried

```
@media all and(max-width:500px){
     .breadcrumb{
          font-size: 10px;
     }
     .breadcrumb li a{
          padding:10px 0 10px 30px;
     }
}
```

My Breadcrumb Code

```
function get_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        the_category(' &bull; ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                the_title();
            }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
        echo '"<em>';
        echo the_search_query();
        echo '</em>"';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should display the generated HTML instead of PHP since your question is a frontend related one (or so it seems).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post the PHP function. Post the HTML that is output. Also, we need to see more CSS. Maybe something is overriding your styles. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the name of the theme you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this CSS to your theme's Custom CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 860px) {
     .breadcrumb, .breadcrumbs li a, .breadcrumb a{
          font-size: 10px !important;
     }
     .breadcrumb li a{
          padding:0px;
     }
}
```